# Build tools in Excel which do not need an end user installation

Tags: vba, vsto

Is it possible to build tools/add-in's in Microsoft Excel which do not need an end user installation.

For example we use VBA to build excel based tools but the language is very basic. Are there any other technologies similar to VBA or VSTO ..?

Thanks,
Jayanth

Comment: Excel has a COM Object Model (Which is what VBA is bound to) so any language that can use COM can be used to automate Excel.  Personally I would not worry about the need for an install.

Answer (score 0):

1. No. (although Admins can do it for users) But all the user has to do is double click something (excel sheet, word document, batch file, vbsfile, jscript, exe (type `iexpress` in **Start - Run**).
2. It's called Visual Basic so yes it is Basic. But the language is simple to write and is anything but basic in capabilities. It can do anything that any other language can do. With COM it can do in 10 lines that takes a C programmer hundreds. Anything any other language can do so can VB/VBA, usually in far less lines.

Perhaps you should think about your questions.

Number 1 is a favourite of those wanting to write viruses, that's why it's impossible to install code without someone's permission. Depending on circumstances, it may be against the law.

Number 2, I suspect you really don't know how to use VBA. Remember there is VBA and  Excel and they are separate. If you've been programming Excel you probably haven't learnt much VBA, more likely you've learnt Excel's object model.

Remember VB6 and VBA is same language (and vbscript is pasteable into both VB6/VBA) hosted differently. If looking for solutions look at VB6/VBA/VBScript. It's a cinch to write a basic spreadsheet in VBA/VB6/VBScript.

VB6/VBA are easy COM programs and their are thousands of objects to play with. Can call API calls so can do anything.

Here's a program that randomises lines in a text file. It is VBScript and adodb (the main windows database object). It creates a database in memory, adds a random number and the line of text, sorts it, writes the database out.

```
Sub Randomise
    Randomize 
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    With rs
        .Fields.Append "RandomNumber", 4 

        .Fields.Append "Txt", 201, 5000 
        .Open
        Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
            .AddNew
            .Fields("RandomNumber").value = Rnd() * 10000
            .Fields("Txt").value = Inp.readline
            .UpDate
        Loop
        .Sort = "RandomNumber"
        Do While not .EOF
            Outp.writeline .Fields("Txt").Value
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Or a script to speak lines of text.

```
Sub Speak
        Set objVoice = CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice")
        Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
            Line=Inp.readline
            outp.writeline Line
            objVoice.Speak Line
        Loop
End Sub
```

Or perhaps you would like to add a macro language to your projects. This  runs a vbs script specified on a command line against every line of of a file. This includes syntax checking etc,

```
Sub VBSCmd
    RawScript = Arg(1)
    'Remove ^ from quoting command line and replace : with vbcrlf so get line number if error
    Script = Replace(RawScript, "^", "")
    Script = Replace(Script, "'", chr(34))
    Script = Replace(Script, ":", vbcrlf)
    'Building the script with predefined statements and the user's code
    Script = "Dim gU" & vbcrlf & "Dim gdU" & vbcrlf & "Set gdU = CreateObject(" & chr(34) & "Scripting.Dictionary" & chr(34) & ")" & vbcrlf & "Function UF(L, LC)" & vbcrlf & "Set greU = New RegExp" & vbcrlf & "On Error Resume Next" & vbcrlf & Script & vbcrlf & "End Function" & vbcrlf

    'Testing the script for syntax errors
    On Error Resume Next
    set ScriptControl1 = wscript.createObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl",SC)
        With ScriptControl1
            .Language = "VBScript"
            .UseSafeSubset = False
            .AllowUI = True
        .AddCode Script
    End With
    With ScriptControl1.Error
        If .number <> 0 then
            Outp.WriteBlankLines(1)
            Outp.WriteLine "User function syntax error"
            Outp.WriteLine "=========================="
            Outp.WriteBlankLines(1)
            Outp.Write NumberScript(Script)
            Outp.WriteBlankLines(2)
            Outp.WriteLine "Error " & .number & " " & .description
            Outp.WriteLine "Line " & .line & " " & "Col " & .column
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    ExecuteGlobal(Script)

    'Remove the first line as the parameters are the first line
    'Line=Inp.readline  
    Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
        Line=Inp.readline
        LineCount = Inp.Line        
        temp = UF(Line, LineCount)
        If err.number <> 0 then 
            outp.writeline ""
            outp.writeline ""
            outp.writeline "User function runtime error"
            outp.writeline "==========================="
            Outp.WriteBlankLines(1)
            Outp.Write NumberScript(Script)
            Outp.WriteBlankLines(2)
            Outp.WriteLine "Error " & err.number & " " & err.description
            Outp.WriteLine "Source " & err.source

            Outp.WriteLine "Line number and column not available for runtime errors"
            wscript.quit
        End If
        outp.writeline temp
    Loop
End Sub
```

And a change of pace from objects to API calls.

This creates a Richtext control that was released after VB6 so isn't built in.

```
Ret = LoadLibrary("c:\windows\system32\MSFTEDIT.dll")
    If Ret = 0 Then MsgBox "Load Lib " & Err.LastDllError
    Flags = WS_CHILD + WS_HSCROLL + WS_VSCROLL + WS_VISIBLE + ES_MULTILINE + ES_AUTOHSCROLL + ES_AUTOVSCROLL + ES_NOHIDESEL + ES_WANTRETURN
    Dim barray() As Byte
    barray = "RICHEDIT50W" & vbNullChar
    gRtfHwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_ACCEPTFILES + WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, barray(0), "", Flags, 0, 0, ScaleX(Me.ScaleWidth, vbTwips, vbPixels), ScaleY(Me.ScaleHeight, vbTwips, vbPixels), Me.hWnd, vbNull, App.hInstance, vbNull)

    Ret = SendMessageByVal(gRtfHwnd, EM_SETTEXTMODE, TM_MULTILEVELUNDO + TM_PLAINTEXT + TM_MULTICODEPAGE, 0)
    If GetTextMode(gRtfHwnd) <> 41 Then MsgBox "get Text mode = " & GetTextMode(gRtfHwnd)
    Ret = SendMessageByVal(gRtfHwnd, EM_SETEDITSTYLE, SES_ALLOWBEEPS + SES_USECRLF, SES_ALLOWBEEPS + SES_USECRLF)
    Ret = SendMessageByVal(gRtfHwnd, EM_SETLANGOPTIONS, IMF_None, IMF_None)
    If GetTextMode(gRtfHwnd) <> 41 Then MsgBox "get Text mode (2) = " & GetTextMode(gRtfHwnd)
    Ret = SendMessageByVal(gRtfHwnd, EM_SETTYPOGRAPHYOPTIONS, TO_None, TO_None)
    'Below is the default anyway with CreateWin flags spec above
    Ret = SendMessageByVal(gRtfHwnd, EM_SETOPTIONS, ECO_AUTOHSCROLL + ECO_AUTOVSCROLL + ECO_NOHIDESEL + ECO_WANTRETURN, ECOOP_OR)


    SetFocusAPI gRtfHwnd
    Me.Show

Dim ParaFormat As ITextPara
Dim FontFormat As ITextFont
Ret = SendMessageAny(gRtfHwnd, EM_GETOLEINTERFACE, 0, TomObj)
```